# If a www. subdomain via a CNAME record pointing to a host address comes up with errors is it a server fault or a DNS settings issue?

Tags: networking, dns, domain

Context of the below question:

I set up three domains for use on a hosted blogging service https://write.as as instructed here: https://howto.write.as/setting-up-a-custom-domain I feel as though I have exhausted all of their support avenues as seen here: https://discuss.write.as/t/www-and-ssl-handshake-failed-error-code-525-issue-with-domain-on-write-as/6767

I have set up the following domains on this hosted blogging platform via different registrars, which at this point seems to be the only difference on my end:

- writecropley.blog with Namecheap, works fine
- alien.observer with Namecheap, works fine
- twisted.place with Gandi.net, works fine
- however, the www. does not work on the CNAME record.

For the last 24 hours or so, I have not changed any DNS settings whatsoever.

As you can see from the forum link, I posted and the screenshots below, I just can't work out anything wrong on my end at this point. The only significant difference is the registrar, the only other thing could be DNS propagation, but I also want to be sure of...

**If a www. subdomain via a CNAME record pointing to a host address comes up with errors (specifically DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) is it a server fault (in this case, write.as?) or a DNS settings issue?**

I think it could be a possibility the SSL certificate could have generated fine for two domains, inclusive of the www. sub domain but on the twisted.place domain it has not for some reason?

The exact DNS settings work on different domains on a domain registrar (Namecheap), so I just can't see why this subdomain is not working as intended. I don't believe it's an issue with DNS propagation because I usually wait 24 to 72 hours before making another change.

#### Some screenshots:

[- Namecheap settings on a different domain where it works fine with the subdomain, www.alien.observer or www.writecropley.blog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV7JH.png)

[- Gandi DNS settings for domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZyuB.png)

If you need any further information, then please ask. I am looking for advice mainly on next steps, because I feel at this point I have exhausted all other avenues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If a www. subdomain via a CNAME record pointing to a host address comes up with errors (specifically DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR) is it a server fault (in this case, write.as?) or a DNS settings issue?**

Was the original question and I can't stress this enough for the context of the following correct answer.

It was in fact a DNS issue, for this problem specifically. Basicaly, Gandi did now allow me to use the www. subdomain where Namecheap did on this particular service, it would seem somewhere in the pipeline respective of the SSL certification process. The other answer to this pertains to the current status of the URL which I done away with, twisted.place I am no longer using it, instead I just set up a different domain on namecheap.

So overall with this https://discuss.write.as/t/www-and-ssl-handshake-failed-error-code-525-issue-with-domain-on-write-as/6767/13 and this combined https://serverfault.com/questions/1092725/domain-registrar-allows-cname-for-root-domain-is-this-reliable

In simple terms both detailed links point to a DNS issue, however more specifically the DNS can vary from registrar to registrar, where Gandi did not allow this CNAME record whereas namecheap does.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if DNS is configured properly and resolving from major providers by using a service like https://www.digwebinterface.com

Enter the domain name, in this case `www.twisted.place` and choose **CNAME** as the **Type** and the **All** option under **Nameservers**. You can also just check if the configuration is correct on your authoritative DNS server by selecting the **Authoritative** option.

Here is a snippet of the results that would be provided as of this post:

```
www.twisted.place@ns-113-b.gandi.net.:  Copy results to clipboard 
www.twisted.place.  10800   IN  CNAME   webredir.vip.gandi.net.
```

As you can see, it does not point to `me.writeas.com`

However, if you do the same for `www.writecropley.blog`

```
www.writecropley.blog@dns2.registrar-servers.com.:  Copy results to clipboard 
www.writecropley.blog.  1799    IN  CNAME   me.writeas.com.
```

The output for this domain is correct.

Now that you know it is a DNS configuration, you can contact your registrar for support.

My recommendation would be to keep your **TTL values** as short as possible until you verify everything is working. This ensures that any changes you make to your DNS records will be removed from cache more quickly. Something like 5 minutes would be ideal if your provider allows for that. Once you have tested everything is working, you can increase it to 60 minutes or longer.